# ActionBar title with two colors

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

Is it possible to have `ActionBar` title composed with two colors defined only by XML styles? At this time I achieve this with `SpannableString` in Java code, but there is one disadvantage. When application starts, title has for some time (until onCreate() called) default style.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create custom Action Bar using below method, i didn't do all of this its just tip to create custom action bar using your method.

Create custom action bar view using this method. remember this is not activity_main.xml create custom_actionbar.xml and past this line.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="rrrrrrrr--"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="tttttttt"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

MainActivity class is

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);

    TextView mTitleTextView1 = (TextView) mCustomView
            .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    mTitleTextView1.setText("DCBA");
    mTitleTextView1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

    TextView mTitleTextView2 = (TextView) mCustomView
            .findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    mTitleTextView2.setText("ABCD-");
    mTitleTextView2.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);

    mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
}
```

}